# Trying to understand the xml definition of user flows

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

When I create a user flow, I have a download button available that allows me to download an XML definition a a custom policy:

[image]

I like to use the xml file to understand it and use snippets for my own custom policy definitions.

However, the downloaded policy xml file includes a relying part has a reference to a user journey that defined somewhere outside the file:

[image]

In above example the user journey is called `B2CSignUpOrSignInWithPassword_V3`.

Is there anywhere I can read the definition of `B2CSignUpOrSignInWithPassword_V3`?
Where is `B2CSignUpOrSignInWithPassword_V3` documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not.

It's a pity that you can't download a user flow and then upload it as a custom policy.